# How kendo Chunk upload work with api in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, api, kendo-upload

Unable to Upload file

```
 <kendo:upload name="files">
        <kendo:upload-async autoUpload="true" chunkSize="1100" saveUrl="saveUrl" removeUrl="${removeUrl}" />
      </kendo:upload>
```

IN COMPONENT

```
uploadSaveUrl = 'sAVEURL'; // should represent an actual API endpoint
  uploadRemoveUrl = 'removeUrl'; // should represent an actual API endpoint

  myFiles: Array<FileInfo>=[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Chunk upload is currently not supported by the Kendo UI Angular Upload.